# Can't install SSMS, complaining about Visual Studio 2008 when it's not even installed

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

So I just got a new windows 7 laptop, and i'm trying to get it all setup and ready for development.  I installed Visual Studio 2010 professional and updated it to service pack 2.  However, whenever I attempt to install Sql Server 2008 R2 it fails with the following error:

> **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup**
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> Another version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 has been detected on this system that must be updated to SP1.  Please update all Visual Studio 2008 installations to SP1 level, by visiting Microsoft Update.
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1&EvtType=0xDF039760%25401201%25401

I attempted to re-install Sql Server 2008 to no avail.  No matter what I cannot stop getting this error.  I do not have visual studio 2008 installed on my machine at all, so I am not sure why it is complaining about it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue by following the instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/joy/how-to-remove-visual-studio-2008-manually) to manually uninstall visual studio 2008

Answer (score 2):

I used the [Visual Studio 2008 Uninstall tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=105801) and it worked fine for me.

> You can use this tool to uninstall Visual Studio 2008 official release and Visual Studio 2008 Release candidate (Only English version).

Found here, on the MSDN Forum:  [MSDN forum topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/d464ff4b-e1da-4b9f-bec7-4477e16f0350).

Answer (score 0):

You might have had Visual Studio 2008 Express or similar automatically installed as a dependency of some other program on your system.

Try going to Windows Update and see if an outstanding update will bring it up to SP1.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that the SP1 won't show up on windows update. If it doesn't, it should be available form microsoft's webiste.

Comment: already tried that, nothing shows.  Furthermore, attempting to install Vs2008 SP1 says that no version of VS2008 is currently installed